# How to use Jquery on the table that I echo from another php?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I echo a whole table to the div and then I can't access the id of it by some reason via jquery, what should I do?

I don't know how to ajax the datatable so I echo the whole table with post and it all work fine.

No error just can't access ID of button In the table I echo

I don't know what line of code I should provide here because everything work fine except I can't access the id of the button in the datatable that I echo from fetch.php to index.php

I checked with inspect mode and the ID are there with everything (ex. $(#'PROID112').click(function() ) <- the id of the buttons was all in place

Solution:
I fixed it myself by changing

$('#id').click(function())

to

$(document).on('click', '#id', function()

thank you everyone for your answer ;)

Comment: alright, I removed the repeat sentence, please answer my question ;) and I don't know what to learn there because it might not relate to jquery so I try asking question here.

Answer (score 0):

try `document.getElementById("div_id").load();` or `$.get();` at the end of the function (and before `return true/false;` if used) if that doesn't work then try with the function that inserts the data into the `<div>` outside of `$(document).ready(function(){});` also since there is no code sample of the function to know what you are using, check you are not using `.text()` to load the data, use `.html()` instead to tell the browser its html and not just text or `.load(url)` to load the url data directly into the div.

Answer (score 0):

write jquery code inside the success function after the table code it will be accessible

```
success:function(){
    //your table code

    $('$id').html();     ///or whatever you want to do 
}
}
```